# How to build a communication between nodejs and java?

Tags: node.js, io

I have Foo.java file

```
package mypack;
class Foo {
  public int add (int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
  } 
}
```

and a Bar.java

```
package mypack;
class Bar {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Foo instance = new Foo();
    System.out.println(Foo.add(2, 3));
  }
}
```

and I have a server.js file in which I am using [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) to read the outputs and print it in the terminal shell.

```
var shelljs = require('shelljs');

shelljs.exec('java -cp bin mypack.Bar', function (code, output) {
   console.log(output);
});
```

when I run `node server.js`
I get the output

```
5
5
```

The first one is getting printed by the java print statement while the second one is printed by nodejs console statement.
My question is how can I modify the java output such that it will only be read by the node and not printed in the shell?
so, that I get only the output from the node console statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a `silent` option which tells it not to print program-output to console:

```
shelljs.exec('java -cp bin mypack.Bar', {silent: true}, function (code, output) {
   console.log(output);
});
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs).